# How findOne in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How find comment inside commentUnders?

```
comments: [{
    nickName: {type: String, required: true}, 
    comment: {type: String, required: true}, 
    commentUnders: [{
        nickName: {type: String, required: true}, 
        comment: {type: String, required: true}, 
    }]
}]
```

I tried this but it did not work.

```
Post.findOne({'comments._id' : req.body._idComment}, 
    {'comments._id': $elemMatch: req.body._idComment,
     'commentUnders._id': $elemMatch: req.body._idCommentUnders}, function(err, data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: where is '_id' in your comments document?

Comment: @JBone mongo created this by default. With this all okay.